# UINavigationView in Apple sample code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am going thru a sample code on Apple developer resource, [tabster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tabster/Introduction/Intro.html) and I couldn't really understand how did they define the navigation Controller in the app.

Would appreciate if someone actually give me some pointers here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** the navigateionviewcontrollers get created with interfacebuilder as subcontrollers of the tabbarcontroller. you can see the setup if you visit MainWindow.xib and expand the tabcontroller =)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I am asking about the UINavigationController that they have in 3 different tabview. And yeah, I did read the readme.txt

Comment: Nice. This is where I don't understand.

Comment: see my updated answer. no need to downvote. hint. in xcode use file>find in project: `NavigationController`

Comment: Sure, this is the part which I don't understand, he didnt define a navController in Appdelegate.h.

Comment: ill give you a hint first to figure it out by yourself (always more fulfilling). try setting a breakpoint at the beginning of the function that i quoted for you and then go through it step by step, carefully reading what is happening and where the code jumps. this way sou should be able to figure out how it works :) otherwise come back here and we'll try to explain it :)

Comment: or better set the breakpoint at the beginning of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9276/discussion-between-revolver-and-sebastian-fluckiger)